# How to setup opencv on other linux machine without recompile

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu

Here is the situation: I have compile opencv3.1 on ubuntu, and then I want to set this compiled opencv on other ubuntu machine, what should I do? if I just copy it, in cmakelist, find_package(OpenCV) would not work

Comment: You can create an "install.log" : The text output from `sudo make install`. Then make a "result.tar" with the installed files. Create a package like this example : `1-opencv31_[version]-1ubuntu16_amd64.deb` from "result.tar". And install the "package.deb" with gdebi.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for your reply, have you success with this way?

Comment: Building packages.deb from install result is something I do very often.   Short example https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032618/18-04-cant-run-grub-customizer/1032932#1032932 ... **Conditions** : Build on older OS, use with newer OS. Not vice verca. ... So please specify the "build OS", and the target.